# Disabling PEP-257 warnings in ]vim python-mode

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I know that I can disable pylint warnings by leaving a comment `# pylint: disable=XXXX`.

How do I do the same thing for pep257 errors?

```
1 C0110 Exported classes should have docstrings. [pep257]
2 C0110 Exported definitions should have docstrings. [pep257]
```

I am writing unit tests and (I believe) I do not need to worry about docstrings for every single test method - everything is quite self-explanatory.

I am using the https://github.com/klen/python-mode.

Comment: Did you try setting up a pylintrc?  Personally, I like to use use pyflakes.vim for within-a-file errors, and set up pylint to run from a Makefile for a project as a whole (or to run a test script along with its dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you followed the recommended pathogen installation,

```
.vim/bundle/python-mode/pylint.ini
```

has a disable = line to which you may add C0110